# holomorphic range of a zero variety

Tags: several-complex-variables

Let D be the unit disk, and $d\ge 2$. $F=(f_1,...f_d)$ is a holomorphic map over the closure of $D^d$ to $C^d$. What information can we get about the image of $\{0\}$x $D^{d-1}$ under $F$?

Hope some characterization about it. Is it locally contained in a zero variety?

e.g: $F(\{0\}$x $D)=\{(f(t),g(t)):t \in D\}$. where $f$ and $g$ are holomorphic on the closure of $D$.

Comment: I learned that the image of a zero variety under a holomorphic map is contained in a union of countably many zero varieties, but I can not find the reference.